# Resetting the count of variable in a while loop

Tags: python, bbc-microbit

```
from microbit import *
from ssd1306 import initialize, clear_oled
from ssd1306_stamp import draw_stamp
from ssd1306_img import create_stamp
from ssd1306_text import add_text
import utime as time
window = []  
threshold = 550  # limit
count = 0 
sample = 0 
beat = False  
start = False
good = create_stamp(Image.HAPPY)
bad = create_stamp(Image.SAD)
heart = create_stamp(Image.HEART)
values = []  
def mean(datalist):
    sum = 0 
    for i in datalist:  
        sum += i 
    if len(datalist) > 0:  
        return sum/len(datalist)  
    else:
        return None 
while True:
    if button_a.was_pressed():
        while True:
            signal = pin1.read_analog()   
            window.append(signal)  
            avg = round(mean(window)) 
            values.append(avg) 
            if len(window) == 11:    
                window.pop(0)  
            if beat is False and avg >= threshold+10:
                beat = True 
                count += 1  
                display.show(Image.HEART, wait=False) 
                if count == 1:  
                    t1 = time.ticks_ms() 
                if count == 11:  
                    t2 = time.ticks_ms()  
                    T = t2 - t1     
                    bpm = round(600*1000/(T)) 
                    display.scroll(str(bpm)) 
                    initialize()
                    clear_oled()
                    add_text(0, 0, "Heart rate :")
                    add_text(0, 3, str(bpm) + " bpm")
                    if 60 <= bpm <= 100:
                        draw_stamp(38, 24, good, 1)
                    else :
                        draw_stamp(38, 24, bad, 1)
                    count = 0  
                    sleep(2000)
                if button_b.was_pressed():
                    break
                    count = 0
            elif beat is True and avg <= threshold-10:
                beat = False 
                display.clear()  
                sample += 1  
            if sample == 250:  
                threshold = mean(values)
                values = []  
                sample = 0  
            sleep(20)  
        sleep(20)
```

This is the code connect to the microbit, and the function is about the heart rate sensor, which it will appear the average beat per minute when sensing 10 beats of the heart.

I am thinking of adding a function that if button b is pressed, the loop will pause, and press the button a to start again. I tried to add a break function in the loop, it worked when I click the button b, it pause the loop, however, the count of beat won't reset, and the time between the beat is also recorded although I break the loop.

Is there any way that I can break the loop and reset the count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reset the counter before breaking. In your current code the line for the count is not executing since it breaks out before it reaches it.

```
if button_b.was_pressed():
    count = 0
    break
```